# unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055) Windows 7 / Firefox 22

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver

System:

- Windows 7 Professional 64-bit
- Firefox 22.0
- Ruby 1.9.3p392 (2013-02-22) [i386-mingw32]
- selenium-webdriver (2.33.0)
- watir (4.0.2)
- watir-webdriver (0.6.2)

I have seen that this question has been asked on numerous occasions before. After a couple of hours trying the suggested solutions, I am still getting nowhere. The command launches an instance of Firefox displaying a blank page and then errors out:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'watir-webdriver'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
```

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Try setting `$DEBUG = true` and see if you get any more specific information on the problem.

Comment: I tried to reproduce this issue by changing versions of selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver, watir but I couldn't reproduce this. I'm also confused what is the cause of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you update your 'watir-webdriver' gem to 0.6.4 and check it once.

My PC configuration is

1. Windows 7 Professional 64-bit
2. Firefox 22.0 Ruby 1.9.3p392
3. Ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32]
4. selenium-webdriver (2.33.0, 2.32.1, 2.32.0)
5. watir-webdriver (0.6.4, 0.6.3)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem in the past, with configuration pretty much like you have.

My understanding is that Firefox tends to break compatibilities when moving from one release to another.

I solved this by switching to Firefox 17 ESR, which is the long life supported version, much more suitable for non casual users.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox 22 will not be supported until Selenium 2.34.0 (It may work for some scenarios at the moment, but generally speaking it doesn't work).

I would suggest rolling back to FF21.